# How does Docker-Desktop behave when a container, initially executed with docker-compose and arguments, is restarted?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Let's say I have a complex container that I start with the following command:

```
docker-compose --env-file ./src/.env -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
```

As you can see, I use a custom `.env` file and override my `docker-compose.yml` file with another one. What happens in Docker-Desktop when I restart my container? I ask because those flags don't seem to be reused when I restart my container, at least for my `.env` file.

Comment: I would not expect the behavior to be any different in Docker Desktop compared to other Docker setups.  I would expect Docker to stop the main process in the affected container, and re-run the same command with the same environment in the same (possibly modified!) container filesystem.  What behavior are you actually seeing?  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating some difference?

Comment: it seems that the file with my environment variables that I pass with `--env` is not used when I restart my container but I will verify this. I do not have a minimal repro yet

Comment: Does `docker-compose ... up --force-recreate your-container` work more reliably?

Comment: Ok I did a minimal repro and indeed, my .env file is taken into account when I restart my container. Like that I'm sure, so no need of `--force-recreate`, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variables of your env file are added to the container at creation time (`docker compose up`). Afterwards, they're assigned to your container and you can inspect them with the `docker inspect` command. They are not removed at container restart, however they will be lost when you recreate the container without passing the env file again.